# Errors setting up a custom equation environment using \tcbhighmath

Tags: macros, environments, package-writing

Currently, I'm writing a Macros package to store my custom environments and macros for my homework sheets. I'm trying to create a custom environment which I can define within my package (a .sty file), that will essentially do the following,

```
\begin{equation*}
  \tcbhighmath{x^2 + y^2 = z^2} % For the sake of example
\end{equation*}
```

In context of the preferences I have set in my full document,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Macros} % My macros file. 
\usepackage[skins, theorems]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{highlight math style={enhanced,
  colframe=white, colback=blue!10!white, arc=0pt, boxrule=1pt}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
    \tcbhighmath{x^2 + y^2 = z^2}
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

The above code produces the following in context,
[image: x^2 + y^2 = z^2]

However, when I tried using the environ package to define my environment after I added my preferences with `\tcbset`, I came across numerous errors.

The code I had used within my .sty file is the following,

```
\RequirePackage{environ}
\RequirePackage[skins, theorems, most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{highlight math style={enhanced,
  colframe=white, colback=blue!10!white, arc=0pt, boxrule=1pt}
}
\NewEnviron{boxed}{
  \begin{equation*}
    \tcbhighmath{\BODY}
  \end{equation*}
}
```

I would be grateful if you could enlighten me as to what my mistake is, and potentially a way that I could still implement code for this environment within a custom package (for the sake of autonomy in future homework tasks).

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `boxed` as the environment's name, because it's already taken and you get

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \boxed already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

Use a different name and don't use `environ`, see the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[skins, theorems]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
  highlight math style={
    enhanced,
    colframe=white,
    colback=blue!10!white,
    arc=0pt,
    boxrule=1pt
  },
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{boxedeq}{b}{%
  \begin{equation*}\tcbhighmath{#1}\end{equation*}%
}{\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

\begin{boxedeq}
x^2 + y^2 = z^2
\end{boxedeq}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, this does exactly what I want, thanks so much for the assistance!